# Symbol lookup error (linux - c++)

Tags: c++, linux, linker-errors

i'm working on multi-agent system like `Robocup soccerrSim2d` On Gnu-linux .
My distb is Ubuntu 11.10(kernel 3.2 - gcc 4.6 )

I installed [librcsc](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/rctools/downloads/51941/librcsc-4.1.0.tar.gz/) from source . (it compiled and installed successfully)

then I installed [agent2d](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/rctools/downloads/51943/agent2d-3.1.0.tar.gz/) from src . (it compiled and installed successfully too !)

But there is a problem with running the agent2d code : (when I run `src/start.sh` : )

this Error happens :

> ./src/sample_player: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/local/lib/librcsc_agent.so.7: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN4rcsc9UDPSocketC1EPKci

What do you think about it guys? Actually, when does "Symbol lookup Error " happen?

Answer (score 5):

Running that symbol through `c++filt` shows that it is `rcsc::UDPSocket::UDPSocket(char const*, int)`.

Since that is, indeed, part of `rcsc`, you need to take a look at `ldd /usr/local/lib/librcsc_agent.so.7`. The entry for `librcsc.so.X` (for some number `X`) there probably says "not found". You must locate the appropriate library (including the numeric suffix that `ldd` said was being searched for) and add the directory containing it to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in the `start.sh` script.