# Orocos LTTng symbol lookup error: /path/to/liborocos-rtt-traces-gnulinux.so: undefined symbol: lttng_probe_register

Tags: c++, linux, linker-errors, lttng

I'm trying to deploy the example Orocos Component with LTTng tracing as described here: http://paul.chavent.free.fr/orocos-traces.html

It seems to locate the `liborocos-rtt-traces-gnulinux.so` share library but fails to locate a LTTng symbol and returns the error:

> symbol lookup error: /path/to/liborocos-rtt-traces-gnulinux.so:
>   undefined symbol: lttng_probe_register

Some suggestions were to change my paths as well as LDFLAGS but no luck. Some leads that I've followed:

- [Symbol lookup error (linux - c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154072/symbol-lookup-error-linux-c)
- https://lists.lttng.org/pipermail/lttng-dev/2014-March/022571.html
- https://www.mail-archive.com/lttng-dev@lists.lttng.org/msg05580.html
- https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the problem was rtt-lttng was not locating the lttng-ust libraries  so I had to find and specify the location.

I only had to alter the CMakeLists of the traces directoy within rtt-lttng:

```
### Trace with lttng-ust

IF (NOT OROBLD_DISABLE_LTTNG_UST)

  MESSAGE("Building tracing lib.")

  find_path(LTTNG_UST_INCLUDE_DIR lttng/tracepoint.h
          HINTS ${PC_LTTNG_UST_INCLUDEDIR} ${PC_LTTNG_UST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

  find_library(LTTNG_UST_LIBRARY lttng-ust
          HINTS ${PC_LTTNG_UST_LIBDIR} ${PC_LTTNG_UST_LIBRARY_DIRS})

  find_library(LIBURCU_BP_LIBRARY urcu-bp
          HINTS ${PC_LIBURCU_BP_LIBDIR} ${PC_LIBURCU_BP_LIBRARY_DIRS})

  set(Lttng_ust_LIBRARIES ${LTTNG_UST_LIBRARY} ${LIBURCU_BP_LIBRARY} -ldl)
  set(Lttng_ust_INCLUDE_DIRS ${LTTNG_UST_INCLUDE_DIR})

  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(   ${Lttng_ust_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
  ADD_LIBRARY(           orocos-rtt-traces-gnulinux SHARED "lttng_ust.c")
  SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES( orocos-rtt-traces-gnulinux PROPERTIES
                         SOVERSION     "${RTT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${RTT_VERSION_MINOR}"
                         VERSION       "${RTT_VERSION}")
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( orocos-rtt-traces-gnulinux ${Lttng_ust_LIBRARIES})

  INSTALL(TARGETS        orocos-rtt-traces-gnulinux
                         LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)

ENDIF(NOT OROBLD_DISABLE_LTTNG_UST)
```